# reinitialize quicksearch on a table?

Tags: jquery, quick-search

I am using jQuery quickSearch to search multiple tables on a single page (one for each).  The problem is some of the data can dynamically change in some of the table fields.  I want quick search to work with that but it doesn't.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Just got a solution

add a "recache" option in the quicksearch plugin and do this in the end of the quicksearch plugin file:

`if( options.recache != null && typeof options.recache == 'function' )
    {

        //alert('binding');
        $(this).bind('recacheQs',e.cache);
    }`

now whenever the data changes just do this `$(your table).trigger('recacheQs');`